# Filtering Sales Grid by SKU - SQL Error

Tags: error, filter, sql, order-grid, sku

When trying to filter the sales order grid by sku i get the following SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`order_id AND x`.`product_type != 'configurable')` LIKE '%A-%')' at line 1, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(' ', x`.`sku) FROM sales_flat_order_item x WHERE main_table`.`entity_id = x`.`order_id AND x`.`product_type != 'configurable')` LIKE '%A-%')
```

Below is the code which i believe is causing the issue:

```
'filter_index' => '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.sku) FROM sales_flat_order_item x WHERE main_table.entity_id = x.order_id AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "filter_condition_callback" attribute to addColumn section,
addColumn function looks like

```
   $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sku'),
        'index' => 'sku',           
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_skuColumnFilter'),
        'type' => 'text',
    ));
```

And call Back function looks like

```
   protected function _skuColumnFilter($collection, $column) {
    $condition = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
    $col_id = $column->getId();
    if (in_array($col_id, array('sku'))) {
        $filter = $condition['like'];
        $collection->getSelect()->where("x.sku LIKE $filter");
    }
    return $this;
}
```

If give me code, i will try to fix the error. 
Thanks.